# Help me understand criteria for $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$

Tags: geometry, notation, ratio

I have a hard time properly understanding the definitions of **similarity** between two triangles (symbolically denoted as $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$). My professor defined similarity like this:

$$\text{If } a': a = b' : b = c': c \text{ then } \triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'.$$

This deduction is obtained via the study of **homotetia.** For a certain triangle $\triangle ABC$ in Euclidean plane, we can choose a point $O$ and connect it to points $A$, $B$ and $C$ with three rays originating in $O$ – we now have $OA$, $OB$ and $OC$. We then choose a point on one of those rays – thus, we get either $OA'$, $OB'$ or $OC'$. The quotient of the length of these line segments will help us to deduce our coefficient of "stretch", $k$. All in all, we can say that $|OA|:|OA'| = 1 : k$. It follows that $k = \frac{|OA'|}{|OA|} = \frac{|OB'|}{|OB|} = \frac{|OC'|}{|OC|}$, which in simpler notation reaffirms the claim $a': a = b' : b = c': c$, and also proves that all of these quotients are equal to the coefficient $k$ ($a': a = b' : b = c': c = k$). This deduction from my professor was very clear and I quickly grasped it. But then I found the following definition in my textbook:

\begin{align*}
&\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C' \text{ if } a : b : c = a': b ': c'. \\
&\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C' \text{ if } (\alpha=\alpha')\wedge (\beta=\beta') \wedge (\gamma = \gamma').\\
\end{align*}

I don't have a problem when it comes to the second line of criteria (I understand the correlation between similarity and angles completely). I *do* however have a big problem with the first line. The textbook dropped it from nowhere, no explanation, no proof, nothing, unlike my professor, who led me through the process of understanding *his* definition of similarity. What I'd like to do is prove that $a': a = b' : b = c': c$ follows from $a : b : c = a': b ': c'$ and/or vice versa.

**So, if possible, I'd prefer if you wrote down proof of the claim $a': a = b' : b = c': c \Longleftrightarrow a : b : c = a': b ': c'$.** If not, I'll have to settle with a proof of $a': a = b' : b = c': c \Longrightarrow a : b : c = a': b ': c'$ or $a : b : c = a': b ': c' \Longrightarrow a': a = b' : b = c': c$.

The thing that *really* confuses me though is the inapplicability of the definition from the textbook in exercises. Here's an example of my claim.

[image]

TRANSLATION: In a square $ABCD$ we fold one of its sides in such a way so that point $B$ "maps" (please, ignore the clumsy terminology) to the midpoint of the line segment $CD$. Show that triangles $HGC$, $EPF$ and $EHD$ are similar and that the lenght of their sides are in relationship $3 : 4 : 5$.

The exercise is not particularly hard. We prove the similarity via proving that the triangles have two (and therefore three) angles of the same size. We get the $x$ relatively quickly by applying the Pythagorean theorem ($x=\frac{5}{8}$). With this value discovered, we can get $a = \frac{3}{8}$, $b = \frac{4}{8}$ and $c = \frac{5}{8}$. After this, we're practically finished. I applied the method my professor suggested and got the following values for the other two triangles:

\begin{align*}
&\triangle EHD; \quad a' = \frac{3}{6} \quad b' = \frac{4}{6} \quad c' = \frac{5}{6} \\
&\triangle EPF; \quad a'' = \frac{3}{27} \quad b'' = \frac{4}{27} \quad c'' = \frac{5}{27}.
\end{align*}

If we accept the definition and the premise of similarity as written in the textbook, then we need to show that the quotient $3 : 4 : 5$ is true for only one of the three similar triangles and we automatically know that the other two also have the quotient $3 : 4 : 5$. At least that is the implication of the dubious definition. But I wanted to make sure. This is my stab at it:

\begin{align*}
a : b : c &= \frac{3}{8} : \frac{4}{8} : \frac{5}{8} = \frac{6}{5}, \\
a' : b' : c' &= \frac{3}{6} : \frac{4}{6} : \frac{5}{6} = \frac{9}{10}. 
\end{align*}

Proposition states: If two triangles are similar, then $a : b : c = a' : b' : c'$. But

$$\frac{6}{5} \neq \frac{9}{10} \Longrightarrow a : b : c \neq a' : b' : c'.$$

The same goes for other combinations of triangles (e.g. $a'' : b'' : c'' = a' : b' : c'$); no equality, only inequalities.

**My second wish: please tell me why I get this result. It seems like the definition of similarity in my textbook is false.**

There are two possibilities: either the proposition in my textbook is **false** or my understanding of the operand "$:$" (and consequently my calculations) is false. I am certain that the latter one is to blame for my confusion. It appears that I have a deep underlying issues of improper understanding of these definitions, and in the end, improper understanding of the concept of similarity as a whole.

Please help me. Explain everything in great detail, so I may finally *truly* understand. I am currently in high school and intend on studying pure mathematics in college. I want to get to the bottom of things, understand, not just pick up some pattern that I was taught and spew it on the test sheet. Without this sense of true understanding, all of my efforts are meaningless.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely misunderstanding something. Did you go to school in a country where $:$ is a division symbol?

Comment: Yes he is, they use it in the picture, see?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes. For example, $a : b$ is $\frac{a}{b}$. This shouldn't be a problem in the context of my textbook, as it cites the "additional" criteria (e.g. $a' : a = b' : b = c' : c$) also with "$:$" right alongside this "problematic" definition, and it works (my professor's definition, that is)! So I am truly confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question: Show that $a:a'=b:b'\implies a:b=a':b'$.

This is Euclid's proposition V.16. Your actual request is for a version of this involving $a,b$ and $c$, but it can be handled two at a time. We assume, with Euclid, that all quantities being put into ratios are strictly greater than $0$. With proportions, we have that the product of the means equals the product of the extremes, thus:

$$a:a'=b:b' \Leftrightarrow ab'=a'b \Leftrightarrow a:b=a':b'.$$

In more conventional notation,

$$\frac{a}{a'}=\frac{b}{b'} \Leftrightarrow ab'=a'b \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'},$$

where we can simply think of the moves as multiplication and division.

---

Now, that answer will only extend to the three-ratio case if we clear up what's going on with the notation $a:b:c$. When we write $a:b:c=d:e:f$, this is shorthand for the two proportions $a:b=d:e$ and $b:c=e:f$, which together imply that $a:c=d:f$. It does *not* represent the equation $(a/b)/c=(d/e)/f$. I think this is why that notation for ratios is not very common anymore.

Thus, when you calculate a numeric value for the expression $\frac38:\frac48:\frac58$, it is not meaningful. That expression is not intended to simplify to a single number.

---

Answering your initial question, with this notational clarification in mind, we can proceed as follows:

$\begin{align}
a:a'=b:b'=c:c' &\implies a:a'=b:b' \text{ and } b:b'=c:c' \text { (separating the compound equality)}\\
&\implies a:b=a':b' \text{ and } b:c=b':c' \text{ (alternating proportions by V.16)}\\
&\implies a:b:c=a':b':c' \text{ (definition of triplicate proportion)}
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Two things though: 1. I still do not understand how we can construct $a : b : c$ with "handling two at a time". 2. Could you please Show me how to get $a : b : c = d : e : f$ from $a : b = d : e$ and $b : c = e : f$.

Comment: That's a definition. $a:b:c=d:e:f$ literally just means $a:b=d:e$ and $b:c=e:f$.

Comment: Wow. Could we represent this definition as well-ordered triples in classical number theory (as @HenningMakholm mentioned)?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: Not complextly exactly, since your proposed unfolding would imply that $1:0:1=1:0:2$.

Comment: You could say that the $3$-vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ are parallel, i.e., there exists a real number $k\ne 0$ such that $(a,b,c)=(kd,ke,kf)$

Comment: @HenningMakholm, these are Euclidean proportions, meaning, the kind Euclid himself talked about. Euclid never would have put $0$ in proportion with anything, as he did not consider it a number. I'll modify "my" proposed unfolding (not mine; Euclid's) to specify that the magnitudes are non-zero.

Comment: @GregorPerčič: Except for the question of whether some of the quantities cam be zero (or negative), the concept Tony is explaining is the same one I am explaining, just from a slightly different focus. A minor nitpick though: you're talking about _ordered triples_ here, not "well-ordered" which has a different (and completely unrelated), meaning.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thank you for the comprehensive deduction! You deserve a big tick!

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding the notation
$$ x:y:z = p:q:r $$
You've been taught that $:$ means division, so you think that this is an equality asserting that the results of the divisions $\frac{x/y}z$ and $\frac{p/q}r$ are the same. But that is not what it means!

Something like $x:y:z = p:q:r$ is a (nowadays not extremely common) notation for the claim that the triples $(x,y,z)$ and $(p,q,r)$ are **"in proportion"** to each other -- or less fancily, that the relation between $x$, $y$ and $z$ is the same as the relation between $p$, $q$ and $r$, in a particular sense.

There are various ways to make precise what this means; one that fits a modern number-centric understanding well is

> By $x:y:z=p:q:r$ we mean that there is some number $k\ne 0$ such that $p=k\cdot x$ and $q=k\cdot y$ and $r=k\cdot z$.

It should be clear how this generalizes to different number of operands such as $x:y:z:w=p:q:r:s$, or indeed just $x:y=p:q$.

In particular if $x:y=p:q$ means that there is $k\ne 0$ such that $p=kx$ and $q=ky$, it is a simple matter of algebra to see that this is the case exactly when $\frac xy = \frac pq$ -- where the fractions are now truly dvisions -- except when $y$ and/or $q$ is zero. So in that case this usage is mostly compatible with writing $:$ for division. But this connection does not generalize neatly to more than two elements on each site.

---

The above defines $x:y:z=p:q:r$ as a single, monolithic relation between six quantities, notated with the compound symbol "$::=::$". Some people prefer to write it as $x:y:z\sim p:q:r$ instead, to emphasize that it shouldn't be read as an equality between two things notated $x:y:z$ and $p:q:r$.

But if we really want it to be an actual equality between $x:y:z$ and $p:q:r$, we *could* achieve it by defining

> The notation $x:y:z$ denotes the set $\{(kx,ky,kz)\mid k\ne 0\}$.

And we can then prove that these sets are identical exactly if the monolithic definition of $x:y:s=p:q:r$ above is satisfied.

(But I don't think this definition of $x:y:z$ as a set is *common*. I have seen it a few times in the context of *projective geometry*, but not in elementary geometry or arithmetic).

Comment: I think it was a common notation a long time ago, when everyone still learned geometry from Euclid's Elements.